# Verifying column copy before deleting original column using a ef core migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am using EF-core, migrations first in a production environment. I need to move a column in the db along with all its data to a new table. I was hoping to do this in a migration as well as verifying the copy was the successful before deleting the original column. Can I do this in a migration?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve the same by using a trigger as below

```
    CREATE TRIGGER BCKUP ON
     TABLE BEFORE 
     DELETE.....
        As
       INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES(...)
```